# Query string variable added automatically to the url

Tags: javascript, php, runtime-error, query-string

I am pretty much new to programming and just getting my hands dirty. I am trying to show something to the user depending upon the length of the URL. Following is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Random</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body id="main" style="display:none">
    <h1>
        Paste something
    </h1>
    <form action="abcd.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="URL" placeholder="random url" id="something" required>
        <input type="submit" value="do something">
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    if (window.location.href.length - 1 > 35) {
        alert("redirect");
    } else {
        alert("show");
    }
</script>

</html>
```

In my case, the minimum length of the URL is 35 characters. However, when I add the URL that long for the first time the  "redirect" alert shows up instead of showing the "show" alert. It runs fine the second time. And after I delete the cache, the whole story repeats.

PS: query string variable I get added on its own. For example, when I hit domain.com its written `domain.com/?i=1` in the address bar on its own(Only when I hit the URL for the first time after deleting cache).

How can I make it work in the first go? Any help appreciated.

Comment: why did you define body teg unvisible??

Comment: Because I wanted to show it to the user only when the length of the url is less than 35.

Comment: Why don't you parse query instead? It is a bad approach to do anything based on a query length, as it may change in future w/o changing logic.
For example, open the current page with some params and hash, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268763/query-string-variable-added-automatically-to-the-url?param=value#someHash
And open console and type `document.location`. You will get an object which can be easily parsed.

Comment: Okay. I'll do that but why is it adding  "?i=1" on its own ? Any idea ?

Comment: Moreover in my case the minimum length remains the same till eternity. So I dont think it will matter in the future. what do you say ?

Comment: It does not matter will it change in the future or not. Just check url to include needed strings or parameters to do something. That's a good way. Basing on length - is a bad way. Some external resources/trackers/whatever may add parameters to your url before opening it, you shouldn't rely on length

Comment: > `why is it adding "?i=1" on its own`
May be added by backend with an initial redirect. Hard to say. Can you share a live example?

> `For example, when I hit domain.com its written domain.com/?i=1`
There is no, like, a global rule to add `i=1` parameter. There is a certain case and should be debugged to understand why the parameter is added.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why query string is added the first time page loading. Use below example to remove query string from the URL and calculate the length of the URL without the query string.

```
<script>
  var url=window.location.protocol;
      url +="//"+window.location.host;
      url +=window.location.pathname;
     if(url.length-1 > 35){
       alert("redirect");
     }else{
       alert("show");
     }
</script>
```